# Convert HEX 32 bit from GPS plot on Ruby

Tags: ruby, gps, hex, byte, bit

I am working with the following HEX values representing different values from a GPS/GPRS plot. All are given as 32 bit integer.

#### For example:

*296767 is the decimal value (unsigned) reported for hex number: 3F870400*

#### Another one:

*34.96987500 is the decimal float value (signed) given on radian resolution 10^(-8) reported for hex humber: DA4DA303.*

Which is the process for transforming the hex numbers onto their corresponding values on Ruby?

I've already tried unpack/pack with directives: **L**, **H** & **h**. Also tried adding two's complement and converting them to binary and then decimal with no success.

Comment: Could you give more references? 296767 is '0x0004873F'.to_i(16)  . . . the number is a 32-bit int supplied least-significant byte first. I'm not sure how the float is encoded though.

Comment: @NeilSlater About the float, is a 32-bit signed int which has to be multiplied by 10^(-8) to get the expected value in radian resolution ( 34.96987500 ).

Comment: If you take `34.96987500 * 10^8` to hex, you get `D06FCB6C` .

Comment: @vidrloco: I don't understand that, and it doesn't match any simple manipulation of the hex (unlike the integer you supplied).

Comment: Got it: 34.96987500 is in degrees - you should say so! The conversion to get it is `'03A34DDA'.to_i(16) * 180 / (Math::PI * 10 ** 8)`

Comment: @NeilSlater good catch. You should package up your couple of comments as a tidy answer. :)

Comment: Great @NeilSlater ! So, you are taking the nibbles out of the HEX and transforming it onto low nibble first! Nice :)

Comment: Actually it's bytes (8 bits, 2 hex digits), not nibbles (4 bits, 1 hex digit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are expecting an Integer value:

```
input = '3F870400'
output = input.scan(/../).reverse.join.to_i( 16 ) 
# 296767
```

If you are expecting degrees:

```
input = 'DA4DA303'
temp = input.scan(/../).reverse.join.to_i( 16 )
temp = ( temp & 0x80000000 > 1 ? temp - 0x100000000 : temp ) # Handles negatives
output = temp * 180 / (Math::PI * 10 ** 8)
# 34.9698751282937
```

---

Explanation:

The hexadecimal string is representing bytes of an Integer stored least-significant-byte first (or little-endian). To store it as raw bytes you might use `[296767].pack('V')` - and if you had the raw bytes in the first place you would simply reverse that `binary_string.unpack('V')`. However, you have a hex representation instead. There are a few different approaches you might take (including putting the hex back into bytes and unpacking it), but in the above I have chosen to manipulate the hex string into the most-significant-byte first form and use Ruby's `String#to_i`